# AppCenter Android Build - Custom shell script appcenter-post-clone script fails with command not found

Tags: visual-studio-app-center

I am trying to build native android app on Azure AppCenter. I have custom appcenter-post-clone.sh to be executed just after the source code clone step. The script executes, but fails with command not found. Here is a sample script and error output.

appcenter-post-clone.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -x
ls
pwd
ls -l
```

Build output

```
==============================================================================
Task         : Shell script
Description  : Run a shell script using Bash
Version      : 2.165.2
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/shell-script
==============================================================================
[command]/bin/bash /Users/runner/work/1/s/app/appcenter-post-clone.sh
/Users/runner/work/1/s/app/appcenter-post-clone.sh: line 2: 
: command not found
/Users/runner/work/1/s/app/appcenter-post-clone.sh: line 3: set: -
: invalid option
set: usage: set [--abefhkmnptuvxBCHP] [-o option] [arg ...]
/Users/runner/work/1/s/app/appcenter-post-clone.sh: line 5: ls
: command not found
/Users/runner/work/1/s/app/appcenter-post-clone.sh: line 6: pwd
: command not found
/Users/runner/work/1/s/app/appcenter-post-clone.sh: line 7: ls
: command not found
ls: illegal option -- 
usage: ls [-@ABCFGHLOPRSTUWabcdefghiklmnopqrstuwx1%] [file ...]
```

The pipeline is running on a mac agent. I do not understand if I am using the correct bash shell to execute the scripts.

Comment: I found out the issue. It looks like issue with line breaks as the file was created on windows. Had to change the line breaks from windows to unix. The script worked fine thereafter.